# How to convert an email to an image?

Tags: email, outlook, rendering, html-email

I have to convert the content of several hundard emails in a user's inbox to individual images (one image per email, TIFF or PNG). Is there any programming interface (VBA?) avaiable on Windows Outlook client for this purpose? Processing the emails via POP3 is also acceptable, as long as HTML mail content is supported.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you need to do this for? Does it need to be an image of the HTML version of a message? If so, does it need to be as the message displays in Outlook (e.g. allowing for quirks of Outlook's HTML rendering)?

Comment: It's mainly for archiving purpose. Outlook rendering is not a requirement. Output form any good email client (e.g. Gmail, ThunderBird) is acceptable, as long as it renders the email in both plain text and html format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go down the save as image route, you will probably need to write something yourself. Mainly because it's not a common requirement. So if you're doing that, you need to find a way to:

1. Open the mailbox via POP3, so that you can read the messages
2. Read the relevant MIME section to get the HTML if it's there or the text if there is no HTML.
3. Find functions/libraries to convert the HTML into an image

If you need help with particular parts, you might be better off asking new, specific questions on Stack Overflow. A lot will depend on your programming ability and what can be done in the language(s) you are comfortable with.

All in all, I don't think saving messages as images is a good way of archiving. You would be better off saving the message source. For example, Thunderbird allows you to save messages in **.eml** format, which is basically just the source, so the file can be opened again later.

Alternatively, if it's of financial importance, you might want to purchase a low cost email server from where you can take data backups (that could save you a lot of time). If you want something to act as an audit trail, perhaps get a mail server that has a built in archiving feature.